# Postman install pipeline script fails to run in jenkins on linux server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, postman, pipeline

**The Issue**

Im getting an error when running a pipeline script in Jenkins at this point.

```
steps {
        sh 'curl -o- https://dl-cli.pstmn.io/install/linux64.sh | sh'
      }
```

Output:

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helpersudo: a password is required
```

Output image : [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCg8i.png)

Full Output of console :

```
Started by user Richard Dsouza
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Simple-Book-Api
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Tool Install)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Install Postman CLI)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ curl -o- https://dl-cli.pstmn.io/install/linux64.sh
+ sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  1298  100  1298    0     0   2249      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2253
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  3 21.9M    3  701k    0     0  2020k      0  0:00:11 --:--:--  0:00:11 2021k
 22 21.9M   22 5070k    0     0  3760k      0  0:00:05  0:00:01  0:00:04 3758k
 47 21.9M   47 10.4M    0     0  4568k      0  0:00:04  0:00:02  0:00:02 4568k
 71 21.9M   71 15.7M    0     0  4816k      0  0:00:04  0:00:03  0:00:01 4815k
 93 21.9M   93 20.5M    0     0  4817k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 4816k
100 21.9M  100 21.9M    0     0  4949k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 5191k
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Postman CLI Login)
Stage "Postman CLI Login" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Running collection)
Stage "Running collection" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

**The Pipelne Script :**

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  tools {nodejs "20.10.0 iron lts"}

  stages {
    stage('Install Postman CLI') {
      steps {
        sh 'curl -o- https://dl-cli.pstmn.io/install/linux64.sh | sh'
      }
    }

    stage('Postman CLI Login') {
      steps {
        sh 'postman login --with-api-key PMAK-658ea9396fe7810031f46379-5b8651a564d4c7cad317fe3c8d77e29314'
        }
    }

    stage('Running collection') {
      steps {
        sh 'postman collection run "2532856-89597286-13bc-4eb0-a596-37e0545fd2f8"'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**What Im trying to Do ?**

Connet Postman to Jenkins to run a collection of APIs.

The pipeline script auto generated in postman which is supposed to be added in Jenkins as above :

image:[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfVbF.png)

**My Environment**

OS : Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

**Jenkins : Version 2.414.3**

Comment: Okay I fingured it out myself , I just installed the step on my local machine having the jenkins server and than removed the step of installation of postman from the pipeline script. That solved it.